# How can I open a txt as a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following txt... (I've saved as a dictionary)

```
"{'03/01/20': ['luiana','macarena']}\n"
"{'03/01/21': ['juana','roberta','mariana']}\n"
"{'03/01/24': ['pedro','jose','mario','luis']}\n"
"{'03/01/24': ['pedro','jose','mario','luis']}\n"
"{'03/01/22': ['emanuel']}\n"
```

the problem is that I want to open it as a dictionary, but I don't know how I can do it. I've tried with:

```
f = open ('usuarios.txt','r')
lines=f.readlines()
whip=eval(str(lines))
```

but it's not working... my idea is for example just take the dictionaries that have as a value the next day 03/01/24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to to have only one dict with all the saved dictionaries you can use:

```
import ast

my_dict = {}
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        new_dict = ast.literal_eval(line)
        for key, value in new_dict.items():
            if key in my_dict:
                my_dict[key].extend(value)
            else:
                my_dict[key] = value

print(my_dict)
```

output:

```
{'03/01/20': ['luiana', 'macarena'], '03/01/21': ['juana', 'roberta', 'mariana'], '03/01/24': ['pedro', 'jose', 'mario', 'luis', 'pedro', 'jose', 'mario', 'luis'], '03/01/22': ['emanuel']}
```

Comment: when you write .update, only replace the content of the previous date. For example, on 3/3/20 ... if there are two different contents, it would only keep the last one. If in the Txt, there are 3/3/20: ['pedro'] and then there is another one with '3/3/20': ['juan'], I would like to see '3/3/20': [' Pedro ',' Juan ']

Comment: @jlemosmusi check now, your issue should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

if yo could change the format you are saving the strings from

```
"{'03/01/20': ['luiana','macarena']}\n"
```

to

```
'{"03/01/20": ["luiana","macarena"]}\n'
```

Then you could just do the following:

```
import json

line = '{"03/01/20": ["luiana","macarena"]}\n'
d = json.loads('{"03/01/20": ["luiana","macarena"]}\n')
```

The result would be a dictionary d with dates as keys:

```
>>> {'03/01/20': ['luiana', 'macarena']}
```

Them, it would be just a mater of looping over the lines of your file and adding them to your dictionary.
An alternative approach would be to use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pickle.html) to save your dictionary instead of the .txt, them use it to load from the disk.